# how to set value bootstrap dropdown to hidden value asp.net using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have 4 value all, dropdown Menu Item, another item, item three, the last one

```
<div class="search-bar-dropdown dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-container">
            <p class="dropdown-button js-dropdown-button">All</p>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
                <li>Dropdown Menu Item</li>
                <li>Another Item</li>
                <li>Item Three</li>
                <li>The Last One</li>
            </ul>
        <asp:hiddenfield id="_hdDropDown" runat="server"></asp:hiddenfield>
    </div>
</div>
```

i don't know to how to set value in tag p and tag ul li to hiddenfield using javascript pls help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery, try the following:

```
$(function () {
    $(".dropdown-container p, .dropdown-container ul li").click(function () {
        $("[id$=_hdDropDown]").val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Messed up the selector for the hidden field, I have updated my answer.